# How to know if the message was delivered and read using GetStream

Tags: flutter, getstream-io

I'm using GetStream to implement chat functionality in my app. I'm trying now to implement the Message delivered and read status, like Whatsapp and Telegram.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Very cool that you chose Stream to implement chat in your app.

The Flutter SDK provides you with a lot of data about the `Message` objects. The one that is relevant to you is called `status`.

Quoting from the documentation (see [here](https://getstream.io/chat/docs/flutter-dart/message_format/?language=dart#messages-returned-by-the-api-follow-this-structure:)) it contains the following information:

> Message status: e.g. 'received', 'sending', 'failed'

What you probably want to do is check the `status` of a `message` object and then act accordingly (e.g. show different UI).

Let me know if that helps or if you have further questions! :)

Comment: Thanks for the useful resource; I'm using package stream_chat_flutter version 5.3.0, and the status of the message does not contain the received status. 
This is the  Enum defining the status of a sending message: Sending,  updating, deleting, failed, failed_update, failed_delete, sent. I get those Enum from the package. Do you have any idea how to get the received status?